# Reorder in making bar plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on making a bar plot using the following small data set.

```
> dat <- data.frame(score=c(10, 20, 15, 18), class=factor(c("A", "B", "B", "A")), id=c("C", "D", "E", "F"))
> dat
  score class id
1    10     A  C
2    20     B  D
3    15     B  E
4    18     A  F
```

I want to order the bars based on the score (from low to high).

```
> ggplot(dat, aes(x=reorder(id, score), y=score, fill=class))+
+   geom_col()
```

[image]

It works well.

My question is when I do `x=reorder(id, score)`, `id` is reordered to C, E, F, D, but `score` is not reordered. Why does it work?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me... What do you mean with 'score is not reordered?'

Comment: @Tjebo I didn't explicitly use `y=reorder(score, score)`. So I assume `score` is still in the order of 10, 20, 15, 18, but `id` is reordered to be C, E, F, D. Is that true?

Comment: No. your code makes perfect sense. You are using `reorder` to reorder the factor levels of id by the value of score. In other words: You are nor ordering score, you are ordering "by score".